# ¿Por que la selección de mi datagridview cambia cuando escribo en mi textbox?

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms, datagrid

Cada vez que modifico mi Textbox **(solo acepta valores numéricos)**, la selección de mi **datagridview** cambia cuando escribo valores en el **Textbox**.

Tengo la selección de las celdas de mi **datagridview** en **RowHeaderSelect**.

Aquí el código de el evento **Textbox_KeyPress**.

```
private void txb_clave_r_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar)) && (e.KeyChar != (char)Keys.Back))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
```

¿Hay manera de que la selección del **datagridview** sea persistente o se modifique en código cuando el evento **txb_clave_r_KeyPress** se ejecute?

Comment: Lo que mostras no es suficiente para saber que pasa. Tu grilla no deberia estar conectada de ninguna forma a un textbox, o tenes cosas que los conecten?

Comment: No hay nada que conecte, Solamente cuando se ejecuta ese evento (Ajeno al textbox) se cambia la selección.

Comment: ok, la seleccion no cambia magicamente por algo que pase en otro lado. algo los conecta. Desgraciadamente sin ver que otras cosas pueden ser, no podemos serte de mucha ayuda.. mira [mcve] a ver si haces algo asi y podemos ayudarte...